# Extract the Chr number from the column

Tags: r, dataframe, extract, chr

I have a data frame that has a column containing the chromosome details (1 to 22). I would like to  create another column with only Chr numbers
[image]

Comment: Try `stringr::str_extract(c("chr6_GL", "chr18"), "(?<=^chr)\\d+")`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `stringr` package and `regex` you may achieve what you are searching for but you need to know all possibilities. Maybe if there is only underscore between what you want and annoying information, you can solve your problem using `str_split` and "_" as pattern parameter.

```
library(stringr)
df <- data.frame(chromosome = c("chr6_GL000253v2_alt", "chr6_GL000254v2_alt",
                                "chr6_GL000255v2_alt", "chr6_GL000256v2_alt", "chr4", "chr11",
                                "chr8", "chr12", "chr2", "chr12", "chr4", "chr6", "chr15", "chr4",
                                "chr2"))
df$chromosome_fixed=str_split(df$chromosome,"_",simplify = T)[,1]
```

Comment: While I agree, I think this should be a comment instead of an answer. You could actually create a small example and show your (working) solution for this problem.

Comment: Thanks Martin, you are right, I edited my answer accordingly

Comment: Bast & Martin, thank you very much. This helped me for sure. The new column has Chr in that like Chr1, Chr14 etc --> I just want to get new column with numbers 1,14,2,16 etc

Comment: You can remove "chr" by doing a `substring`
 substring(df$chromosome_fixed ,3)

Answer (score 2):

A solution with the package `data.table`:

**REPREX**

- Code

```r
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

DT[, Chr_ID := lapply(.SD, str_extract,"(?<=^chr)\\d+"), .SDcols = "chromosome"]
```

- Output

```r
DT
#>              chromosome Chr_ID
#>  1: chr6_GL000253v2_alt      6
#>  2: chr6_GL000254v2_alt      6
#>  3: chr6_GL000255v2_alt      6
#>  4: chr6_GL000256v2_alt      6
#>  5:                chr4      4
#>  6:               chr11     11
#>  7:                chr8      8
#>  8:               chr12     12
#>  9:                chr2      2
#> 10:               chr12     12
#> 11:                chr4      4
#> 12:                chr6      6
#> 13:               chr15     15
#> 14:                chr4      4
#> 15:                chr2      2
```

- Your data

```r
DT <- data.table(chromosome = c("chr6_GL000253v2_alt", "chr6_GL000254v2_alt",
                 "chr6_GL000255v2_alt", "chr6_GL000256v2_alt", "chr4", "chr11",
                 "chr8", "chr12", "chr2", "chr12", "chr4", "chr6", "chr15", "chr4",
                 "chr2"))
DT
#>              chromosome
#>  1: chr6_GL000253v2_alt
#>  2: chr6_GL000254v2_alt
#>  3: chr6_GL000255v2_alt
#>  4: chr6_GL000256v2_alt
#>  5:                chr4
#>  6:               chr11
#>  7:                chr8
#>  8:               chr12
#>  9:                chr2
#> 10:               chr12
#> 11:                chr4
#> 12:                chr6
#> 13:               chr15
#> 14:                chr4
#> 15:                chr2
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: You are just extracting the 4th character, so `chr11` is transformed into `1`. I doubt this is a correct solution.

Comment: Oops! You are of course right @Martin Gal. Sorry about that. I just edited my answer based on your previous comment. Thanks again for your feedback

Answer (score -1):

I've created similar column and extracted the numbers to a new column called Number:

```
#Populate a dummy table
df = pd.DataFrame(data=['chr6_GL','chr6_GL00','chr4','chr11','chr8','chr12'], columns=['Data'])
#Extract the numbers using regex and assign it to a new column called 'Number'
df['Numbers']=df['Data'].str.extract(r'chr([0-9]*)')
```

Data    Numbers[image]

Comment: This looks like *Python* code but this is a R related question.